# Is treating two uint8_ts as a uint16_t less efficient

Tags: c++, integer, bignum

Suppose I created a class that took a template parameter equal to the number `uint8_t`s I want to string together into a Big int.

This way I can create a huge int like this:

```
SizedInt<1000> unspeakablyLargeNumber;  //A 1000 byte number
```

Now the question arises: am I killing my speed by using `uint8_t`s instead of using a larger built in type.

For example:

```
SizedInt<2> num1;
uint16_t num2;
```

Are `num1` and `num2` the same speed, or is `num2` faster?

Comment: I'd expect `num2` to be faster, given that operations on it can be done in a single instruction, whereas `num1` will require at least two operations on its `uint8_t` members.

Comment: If you work with at least 16bit processor  most likely `num2` will be faster because for many operations single CPU instruction will be used instead of (supposedly more complex) `SizedInt` methods. But even with 8bit processor I doubt those methods will outperform code built by compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would undoubtedly be slower to use `uint8_t[2]` instead of `uint16_t`.

Take addition, for example.  In order to get the `uint8_t[2]` speed up to the speed of `uint16_t`, the compiler would have to figure out how to translate your add-with-carry logic and fuse those multiple instructions into a single, wider addition.  I'm sure that some compilers out there are capable of such optimizations sometimes, but there are many circumstances which could make the optimization unlikely or impossible.

On some architectures, this will even apply to loading / storing, since `uint8_t[2]` usually has different alignment requirements than `uint16_t`.

Typical bignum libraries, like [GMP](https://gmplib.org), work on the largest words that are convenient for the architecture.  On x64, this means using an array of `uint64_t` instead of an array of something smaller like `uint8_t`.  Adding two 64-bit numbers is quite fast on modern microprocessors, in fact, it is usually the same speed as adding two 8-bit numbers, to say nothing of the data dependencies that are introduced by propagating carry bits through arrays of small numbers.  These data dependencies mean that you will often only be add one element of your array per clock cycle, so you want those elements to be as large as possible.  (At a hardware level, there are special tricks which allow carry bits to quickly move across the entire 64-bit operation, but these tricks are unavailable in software.)

If you desire, you can always use template specialization to choose the right sized primitives to make the most space-efficient bignums you want.  Otherwise, using an array of `uint64_t` is much more typical.

If you have the choice, it is *usually* best to simply use GMP.  Portions of GMP are written in assembly to make bignum operations much faster than they would be otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You may get better performance from larger types due to a decreased loop overhead. However, the tradeoff here is a better speed vs. less flexibility in choosing the size.

For example, if most of your numbers are, say, 5 bytes in length, switching to `unit_16` would require an overhead of an extra byte. This means a memory overhead of 20%. On the other hand, if we are talking about really large numbers, say, 50 bytes or more, memory overhead would be much smaller - on the order of 2%, so getting an increase in speed would be achieved at a much smaller cost.